# Filter only Service and NonInventory type items in QuickBooks item api

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

In [Item API Documentaiton](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/item#query-an-item) we can see there are different types of Item that we can filter/sort from. And I am only interested in `Item.Type = 'NonInventory' OR Item.type = 'Service'`.

#### API query

```sql
SELECT * from Item where Active IN (true, false) AND Type IN ('Service', 'NonInventory')
```

But I only get all items as `Service` Type. Even `NonInventory` type item.type is `Service`. Now how do I determine, which one is `Service` and which one is `NonInventory` by checking the `Status` or any other attribute? Also I want to exclude, `Categories` and `Bundle` from the Response.

Answer (score 0):

After passing `minor_version = 42` in API endpoint, I am getting correct result, and able to filter `Service` and `NonInventory` items only.

Reference: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/explore-the-quickbooks-online-api/minor-versions#minor-version-summary